# How to be with identical in content classes using by Realm

Tags: android, realm

I need to create many identical in content classes like the class below

```
public abstract class AbstractListModel  extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

If I will extend this class in another, it seems I'll have a lot of empty classes, 'cause they have only 2 fields (id and name) wich contains in the mother-class.

```
public class LectureHallListModel extends AbstractListModel {
//@PrimaryKey
//private String id;
//private String name;

//public String getId() {
//    return id;
//}

//public void setId(String id) {
//    this.id = id;
//}

//public String getName() {
//    return name;
//}

//public void setName(String name) {
//    this.name = name;
//}
}
```

Are the any way to add to a DB several identical in content tables without creation empty classes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance of fields (technically from any class that is not directly `RealmObject`) is not supported by Realm.

You would need the following setup:

```
public interface AbstractListModel {
    String getId();
    void setId(String id);
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

And

```
public class LectureHallListModel extends RealmObject implements AbstractListModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But anyway, as I understood I should create many identical classes for the diferrent data-models (tables in future). Can I create only one model and do something with it to create many tables?

Comment: `Can I create only one model and do something with it to create many tables?` no

Comment: Its sad. Thank you very much